# Javascript object destructoring not working within react this.props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just learned about object destructoring a few days ago with simple object and that worked fine. However when I try to use it in react on this.props, it returns undefined for all my variables, I'm not really certain what I am doing wrong here. Any help is much appreciated. Cheers.

```
render() {
    console.log("the properties from props", this.props.currentTeam);
    const {
        metaDataUpdated,
        metaDataUpdating,
        needsToResetUpdateMessage
    } = this.props.currentTeam;
    console.log(
        `metadata updated? ${metaDataUpdated}   --- is metaDataUpdating? ${metaDataUpdating} --- need to update message ${needsToResetUpdateMessage}`
    );
```

[image: java]

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(this.props.currentTeam.metaDataUpdated)`? I ask, because it could be the lazy loading effect of the console when outputting `this.props.currentTeam`.

Comment: Good question. that also gives undefined so I guess somewhere in updating my store via redux doesn't work well. thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @trincot: Found the issue, I forgot to copy my state in an immutable way in the reducer. (Y)

Comment: Good to hear you got it resolved!

Answer (score -1):

Your `console.log` statements are looking at two different things and `console.log` is not reliable at showing things at a specific point in time. If you want to debug things like this, try using this instead:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props.currentTeam)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(metaDataUpdated));
```

Then you'll probably see that there is consistency in the values and your problem is most likely something else having to do with the React lifecycle or the way you are updating the props or state.